# Problems returning cursor from stored procedure as ClientDataset

Tags: delphi, oracle11g, cursor, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

This question directly relates to my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054254/how-to-return-oracle-cursor-from-stored-proc-as-client-dataset-using-delphi-and).

I have a need to create a TClientDataSet on a client from an Oracle 11g cursor contained in a package. I am using Delphi XE2 and DBExpress to connect to the DB and DataSnap to send the data back to the client.

When I configure the TSQLStoredProc to the TClientDataset at design time I can return the cursor as a TClientDataset with no problem and get expected results.

When I try to execute the Stored Procedure at runtime it returns an empty TClientDataset.

Is it possible to configure and execute an Oracle 11g Stored Procedure using TSQLStoredProc at runtime?

### DataSnap Server

**Design time Data Module code [View as Text]**

```
    object StrProc1: TSQLStoredProc
    SchemaName = 'xxxx'
    MaxBlobSize = -1
    Params = <
      item
        DataType = ftWideString
        Precision = 2000
        Name = 'ABBR'
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = 'ZZZTOP' 
      end
      item
        DataType = ftCursor
        Precision = 8000
        Name = 'RES'
        ParamType = ptOutput
        Size = 8000
      end>
    PackageName = 'KP_DATASNAPTEST'
    SQLConnection = SQLConnection1
    StoredProcName = 'GETFAXDATA'
    Left = 408
    Top = 72
  end
  object DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = StrProc1
    Left = 408
    Top = 120
  end
  object ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    ProviderName = 'DataSetProvider1'
    Left = 408
    Top = 176
  end
```

**function to execute Design Time config**

```
function TKPSnapMethods.getCDS_Data3: OLEVariant;
begin    
 self.ClientDataSet1.Open;
 result:= self.ClientDataSet1.Data;
 self.SQLConnection1.Close;
end;
```

**function to execute Runtime configuration** This is the code that returns an empty ClientDataSet. The objective is to connect the pieces, set the value of the parameter, open the CDS and return the CDS.Data

```
function TKPSnapMethods.getCDS_Data2(schema: String): OleVariant;
var
  cds: TClientDataSet;
  dsp: TDataSetProvider;
  strProc: TSQLStoredProc;
  ProcParams: TList;
begin
  strProc := TSQLStoredProc.Create(self);
  try
    strProc.SQLConnection:= SQLCon;//<--A TSQLConnection    
    dsp := TDataSetProvider.Create(self);
    try
      dsp.DataSet := strProc;

      cds := TClientDataSet.Create(self);
      try
        cds.DisableStringTrim := True;
        cds.ReadOnly := True;
        cds.SetProvider(dsp);

        ProcParams:= TList.Create;    
        try
          //Load Stored Procedure Parameters
          SQLCon.GetProcedureParams('GETFAXDATA','KP_DATASNAPTEST',Schema,ProcParams);
          LoadParamListItems(StrProc.Params,ProcParams);
          
          strProc.ParamByName('ABBR').AsString := 'ZZZTOP';//<--Assign Parms
          strProc.MaxBlobSize := -1;
          strProc.SchemaName:= Schema;
          strproc.PackageName:='KP_DATASNAPTEST';
          strProc.StoredProcName:= 'GETFAXDATA';
          cds.Open;
          Result := cds.Data;
        finally
          FreeProcParams(ProcParams);
        end;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(cds);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(dsp);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(strProc);
    self.SQLCon.Close;
  end;
end;
```

**Client Code** this is just a test form that creates a connection to the DataSnap Server executes the ServerMethods and displays the results in a string grid.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 proxy:TKpSnapMethodsClient;
 cds :TClientDataSet;
 field: TField;
 r,c:integer;
begin
  r:=0;
  c:=0;
  SQLConTCPSERV.Connected := True; //TSQLConnection
  proxy:= TKPSnapMethodsClient.Create(SQLConTCPSERV.DBXConnection,false);
  cds:= TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  try
    //cds.Data:= proxy.getCDS_Data2('TESTTH');//<--Runtime function
    cds.Data:= proxy.getCDS_Data3; //<--Design time function
    if cds <> nil then
    begin
      cds.Open;
      cds.First;
      //String grid to display CDS contents.
      strGrid1.ColCount:= cds.FieldCount; //returns correct #
      strGrid1.RowCount:= cds.RecordCount;

      while not cds.Eof do  //<--runtime wont make it past here
      begin
        for field in cds.fields do //loop fields
        begin
          strgrid1.Cells[c,r]:= field.Text; //display results.
          c:=c+1;
        end;
        c:=0;
        r:=r+1;            
        cds.Next;
      end;
    end
    else showmessage('DataSet is NIL');
  finally
    cds.Free;
    proxy.Free;
    SQLConTCPSERV.Connected := False;
  end;
end;
```

Once agian I must confess I am new to the Delphi language. I have searched google, code.google, the Embarcadero Developer Network and DBExpress documentation all to no avail.
I just don't understand why there would be a difference between design time and runtime.

Comment: Please don't include tag information in the subject of your questions; the tagging system here is designed very well, and works without help. Also, it's not necessary to SHOUT any information in your question; even if we might have hearing difficulty, reading comprehension here tends to be very high, and text in ALL CAPITALS is more difficult to read (and quite annoying). We'll see your question just as well without it. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. You say that design-time works but runtime doesn't, but the code in your client side `Button1Click` handler shows two totally separate function calls (`getCDS_Data2('TESTTH1)` and `getCDS_Data3` (no parameter)) and says one of them works, but you only show the code for `getCDS_Data2`. It's hard to compare them and say why one works and the other doesn't when you don't give us the code to compare.

Comment: I have updated the title to remove the tags and the words beginning with capital letters. The code for getCDS_Data3 is included perhaps you have just overlooked it. Do you have any idea why the function would work in design time and not runtime? Thanks

Comment: You're correct. I overlooked it. The code for `getCDS_Data2` is about forty lines of code, while `getCDS_Data3` is three; I guess I expected them to be more similar because you wanted us to explain the different behavior. Can you explain how those are comparable? (The first is about 13x more code, which means apparently that every third line should be equivalent.)

Comment: The reason the functions are so vastly different is because function getCDS_Data3 is getting its component settings from the design time code provided while function getCDS_Data2 is creating and setting its components during runtime. I need to execute stored procedures at runtime because it won't be efficient to drop a component on the data module for each stored procedure I need executed. I would greatly appreciate any input in regards to why a component would behave differently at runtime vs. Design time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. the problem is in the **order** of assigning values to the TSQLStoredProc component.

when calling this code:

```
strproc.PackageName:='KP_DATASNAPTEST';
strProc.StoredProcName:= 'GETFAXDATA';
```

the parameters are cleared. Below is the code to set the StoredProcName found in Data.SqlExpr

```
procedure TSQLStoredProc.SetStoredProcName(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  //if FStoredProcName <> Value then
  //begin
    FStoredProcName := Value;
    SetCommandText(Value);
    if Assigned(FProcParams) then  // free output params if any
      FreeProcParams(FProcParams);
  //end;
end;
```

As you can see if FProcParams are assigned then FreeProcParams is call which frees the params. Because I was setting the StroredProcName after I was assigning the param values the code was executing with cleared params and returning an empty cursor.

the order that produces correct results at runtime [from getCDS_Data2] is as follows:

```
strProc.SchemaName:= Schema;
SQLCon.GetProcedureParams('GETFAXDATA','KP_DATASNAPTEST',Schema,ProcParams);
LoadParamListItems(StrProc.Params,ProcParams);

strproc.PackageName:='KP_DATASNAPTEST';
strProc.StoredProcName:= 'GETFAXDATA';
strProc.MaxBlobSize := -1;
strProc.ParamCheck:=true;

strProc.ParamByName('ABBR').AsString := 'ZZZTOP';

cds.Open;
```

Comment: I find it odd that setting a property of an object would greatly affect another attribute of the object. I'll chalk this up to new language learning curve.